# Mongoose transaction over separate databases

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to create a transaction to create documents in two separate databases using Mongoose. I wrote this piece of code, it creates docs in the databases, but when if I throw an error in the code, the docs still appear in the db's. Can anybody help me figure out what I do wrong?

```
    const mongodb = mongoose.createConnection(MONGODB_URL, mongoOptions);
    const session = await mongodb.startSession();
    session.startTransaction();
    try {
        let db = mongodb.useDb('superUs');
        const OrgModel = db.model('Organization', Organization, 'Organizations');
        const newOrg = OrgModel.create([org, { session }]);

        db = mongodb.useDb('anotherDb');

        const UtilRecModel = db.model('User', User, 'util'); 
        const NewUtilRec = UtilRecModel
            .create([{ username: 'user', password: 'pwd', isAdmin: false }, { session }]);
        session.commitTransaction();
        session.endSession();
    } catch(err) {
        session.abortTransaction();
        console.log('err');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const dbName = `organization-${org.title}`;
    let sessionSuper;
    let sessionOrg;
    try {
        const dbSuper = mongodb.useDb('superUs');
        const dbOrg = mongodb.useDb(dbName);
        const OrgModel = dbSuper.model('Organization', Organization, 'Organizations');
        const UtilRecModel = dbOrg.model('User', User, 'util');

        sessionSuper = await dbSuper.startSession();
        sessionOrg = await OrgModel.startSession();
        sessionSuper.startTransaction();
        sessionOrg.startTransaction();

        await OrgModel.create([org], { session: sessionSuper });
        await UtilRecModel.create([{ username: 'util', password: 'util', isAdmin: false }], { session: sessionOrg });

        sessionSuper.commitTransaction();
        sessionSuper.endSession();
        sessionOrg.commitTransaction();
        sessionOrg.endSession();
    } catch(err) {
        sessionSuper.abortTransaction();
        sessionOrg.abortTransaction();
        sessionSuper.endSession();
        sessionOrg.endSession();
        throw(err);
    }
```